# Freeform Notifications Word Wrap Problem

Tags: solspace-freeform

Is anyone aware of Freeform notifications being sent with 'word wrap' even though the selection is unselected in the settings?

I'm using the most up to date versions of both EE (2.10.1) and Freeform (4.2.2) and cant for the life of me work out how to turn this feature off.

All email notifications are coming through in a right mess. Have also turned the setting off in Admin>Email Configuration too but to no avail.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a little Freeform bug, the "Send Emails as" HTML/Text options aren't going to effect this are they? SolSpace are very active on here so I'm sure they'll come back to you with a succinct answer shortly.

Comment: Thanks and no, I literally tried that last option as a desperate measure. Really strange  as never experienced anything like this before.